# How to reply to a mail meeting invitation with neomutt

Tags: email, mutt

How do I reply to an Ical/ICS/vcal invite in neomutt or more specific with terminal programs. I can import them to calcurse, but I need to reply too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a method to view and reply to ical invitations:

https://github.com/marvinthepa/mutt-ical

Tim Hentenaar's solution can be used for adding invitations to calcurse, and this can be used to view invitations and reply.

Installation instructions from the repository's README:

> mutt-ical.py is meant as a simple way to display and reply to ical invitations from mutt.
>
> It was originally authored by Martin Sander, and later modified by
> Dominic White.
>
> ### Installing
>
> 1. Copy it into somewhere in your PATH, (or you can specify the PATH
>    in your .mailcap) 2) Edit your mailcap (~/.mailcap or /etc/mailcap) to
>    have the following line:
>
>    ```
>    text/calendar; <path>mutt-ical.py -i -e "user@domain.tld" %s
>    application/ics; <path>mutt-ical.py -i -e "user@domain.tld" %s
>    ```
>
> (Don't forget to add your email address)
>
> [ ... ]
>
> ### Usage
>
> To reply, just open the ical file from mutt by:
>
> 1. Viewing the attachements (usually 'v')
> 2. Invoking the mailcap entry (usually 'm')
> 3. Choosing your reply

Comment: The script is unmaintained and the solution does not seem to work with Python3